# using struct value in realloc gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, vector, struct

Using C I have a struct which looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
void * elems;
int logLen;
int allocLen;
int elemSize;
void (*vecFree)(void *);
int initAlloc;
} vector;`
```

I also have functions:

```
void VectorNew(vector *v, int elemSize, VectorFreeFunction freeFn, int initialAllocation)
{   printf("%s\n" , "vecNew");
assert(elemSize > 0);
assert(initialAllocation >-1);
if(initialAllocation == 0) {
    v->initAlloc = 15;
    v->allocLen = v->initAlloc;
}
else {
    v->initAlloc = initialAllocation;
    v->allocLen = v->initAlloc;
}
v->elemSize = elemSize;
v->elems = malloc(v->elemSize*v->allocLen);
v->logLen = 0;
v->vecFree = freeFn;
}
```

and

```
void VectorAppend(vector *v, const void *elemAddr)
{   printf("%s\n" , "vecAppend");
if(v->logLen == v->allocLen)
    growVector(v);
void * dest = point(v,v->logLen,v->elemSize);
dest = memcpy(dest,elemAddr,v->elemSize);
v->logLen++;
}
```

and the `growVector` function looks like this:

```
void growVector(vector *v){
printf("%s\n" , "vecGrow");
v->allocLen +=v->initAlloc;
v->elems = realloc(v->elems,(v->elemSize) * (v->allocLen));
}
```

The problem is during `vectorNew` I pass `elemSize = 1`, `initialAllocation = 4` and other arguments properly.
Then I use `vectorAppend` 4 times. After that I use `vecotrAppend` one more time but `allocLen` is equal to `logLen` so it has to go to `vectorGrow` and that's where segmentation fault takes place.

Comment: What shows the stack trace on failure?

Comment: @Dmitri sorry i forgot point looks like this #define point(start,size,elemSize) ((char*)start+size*elemSize)
and yes its safe, and even if it wasnt its not the problem because i tried it without any printfs. i am adding chars.

Comment: @GiorgiCercvadze why did you say **the problem is during vectorNew** and after **go to vectorGrow and thats where segmentation fault takes place** ? Could you send a complete sample showing parameters of your `VectorAppend()` calls ?

Comment: If you're adding strings (assuming that's what you meant by "adding chars"), are they all `v->elemSize` bytes long, or are some of them shorter?  Could you be `memcpy()`ing some bytes from past the ends of your source strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use your macro `point` wrong.

```
void VectorAppend(vector *v, const void *elemAddr)
{   
    printf("%s\n" , "vecAppend");
    if(v->logLen == v->allocLen)
        growVector(v);

    void * dest = point(v->elems,v->logLen,v->elemSize); // starting point is at v->elems
    dest = memcpy(dest,elemAddr,v->elemSize);
    v->logLen++;
}
```

Explanation: The first entry in your structure (`elems`) points to a memory allocated for the entries of a vector (but it is not memory used for elements itself). You overwrote this field when calling `VectorAppend` for the first time (the program doesn't crash at this point since the memory belongs to the process). Then when you try to call `realloc` your OS looks at the field `elems`, copies the memory that the `elems` field points to to a new location and frees the old memory. Since the overwritten field doesn't point to memory your process has allocated it crashes.

Comment: it worket, thanks a lot but can you explain ? i mean first value of v is elems anyway so why does (char*)v differ from (char*)v->elems?